# How to call this.Page (server page) from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have methos to display content of page at server side like

```
DisplayDetails(Page PageNema)
{
///
}
```

How can i call this function from javascript as well as how can i pass Page argument from Javascript

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain a lot more? You want to call a function in .NET from clientside javascript? If so, use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If it's WebForm you must set this method as WebMethod, so then you can call this method from jQuery. Something like that:
Client Side.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

Server side:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string DisplayDetails()
  {
   //your code to retrieve details here
    return Details;
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding parameters. Pars your values as JSON by using JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string DisplayDetails(parameter1,parameter2,etc...)
   {

      return something;
   }
```

Client side code

```
<script type="text/javascript">



 function  functionName(callback) {



             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: 'PageName.aspx/DisplayDetails',// your function name 
                 data: '{"argument1","argument2",etc...}',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {

                     // If u want something from serverside function then write your code here                                       

                 },
                 error: function (e) {

                 }
             });

         }



 </script >
```